# ``.ipynb`` files using the Jupyter-Microsoft Extensions for VSCode do not get color-themed

Tags: python, themes, visual-studio-code, pylance

I am currently working with `.ipynb` files using the Jupyter-Microsoft Extensions for VSCode. Today all of a sudden, my color-theme for python does not work anymore in the new trusted mode. As in the attached GIF the chosen language for the notebook-bracket appears to be CVE (does this mean conda virtual environment?) instead of Python. Changing it will not make any difference, as can be seen in the GIF. Changing to other languages works as intended. I am using a conda environment as my python interpreter. Both `nb_conda_kernels` and `ipykernel` are installed inside this environment.

I searched through most of the settings, but could not find a solution. I have not (intentiaonally) changed any settings since the last time using. Classic `.py` and `.ipynb` files in untrusted mode get color-themed accordingly.

Has someone got a hint?

[image]

Comment: I further noticed, that also Intellisense is not working...

Comment: Could you try to disable all the extensions you have installed and only enable the python related? Some people have run across this issue too, you can refer to [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/7917).